# Consuming and exposing webservices in one project (.NET)

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, soap

What is best practice concerning consuming and exposing webservices in one project? (.net)

I need to create a rest webservice to expose data.
The rest webservice would need to consume this data from another (SOAP) webservice from a third party. (The data needs to be merged with data present in a database, so I cannot call the SOAP directly)

We are working on creating a class library for consuming the data from the third party (SOAP) and use that in the rest webservice. But is this the correct way to go
?

I could need some advise on this, it is going to be the "core" of the application for future development.

Thanks in advance

Regards, 
Heisa

Comment: In your set up, does `project` also mean `assembly`?

Comment: Hi, yes it also means assenmly

Comment: Is there any concrete problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to enrich the data from one source and combine that with information from another source, I think this is a decent solution.

I think it is better to have one single point to talk to (your REST service), than to have two in your application and merge them together there. The benefit of the single-service pattern is that it is easier to maintain, and you can also reuse the enriched data in other products / devices.

Comment: Thanks! I think so too, but needed the confirmation,